# Facebook graph api upload image withou sdk

Tags: c++, facebook, facebook-graph-api, multipartform-data

Has anyone tried uploading an image using the FB graph api without SDK support? I am trying to do it through the graph api explorer and i always get "Require upload file" response. I am forming the request using multipart/form-data encoding and use the "source" parameter. A sample request that worked would be o great help.

Comment: What language are you developing in?

Comment: @madebydavid C++. Although i want to try the request using graph api explorer or a rest client.

Comment: I don't have any example code for using the Graph API with C++, sorry. I added a C++ tag to your question. Consider adding more to your question, perhaps some code where you initialise the lib you want to use to make the HTTP request. It's possible to do this without the SDK - I've done it myself but in PHP using the curl lib to do the POST where the SDK seemed like overkill.

Comment: Hmm.. i have been trying to post by forming a multipart/form-data encoded image data through graph api explorer (tried both binary image data and base64 encoded binary data) and i have been getting {#324} constantly. Unfortunately, i could not find relevant information in the fb developer documentation.

Comment: yeah, that's not going to work - the Graph API Explorer uses AJAX to make the POST request and you cannot a multipart/form-data request with AJAX. Or at least, the Explorer doesn't give us an interface where we can hack that kind of functionality into it.

Comment: Others have tried in the past - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020025/use-graph-api-explorer-to-post-a-photo

Comment: Thanks @madebydavid i will keep trying from my application. I wish fb had better error messaging.

Answer (score 1):

I write a c example code with openssl. You can focus the http raw data part which is implement in function iotask(). Here is the sample code:

```
/*
  compile:
      gcc -o fb_photo_upload fb_photo_upload.c -lssl -lcrypto
*/

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509_vfy.h>

/*
 * A image hex array. Let's say if you have a image file called 'myimage.png'.
 * then create the hex array as below:
 *     xxd -i myimage.png > myimage.c
 */
#include "myimage.c"

#define BOUNDARY "boundary12345"

char data_file_header[] = \
    "--" BOUNDARY "\r\n" \
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"source\"; filename=\"myimage.png\"\r\n" \
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";

char data_end[] = \
    "\r\n--" BOUNDARY "--\r\n";

int iotask(SSL *ssl) {
    int i, n, content_len;
    char *p;
    char writebuf[1024];
    char readbuf[1024];

    content_len = strlen(data_file_header) + myimage_png_len + strlen(data_end);

    p = writebuf;
    p += sprintf(p, "POST /v2.9/me/photos?access_token=EAAEcZAcqQqtUBAJyBItkYPLQ0URkZAFPwLXDbPZClSl3BgUvCjJk32Y5QvgNSDuuBMoC4VdoSOknQYJWnx7L2ZCZACPx5ZA2xfPd5ZB7gndtlIXoMkNumzIT0YKQkbqHgoJZBs3LWHw2UHZBbz3W9qm6xN4pKXzIAej1kunoBPGShDAABAB HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    p += sprintf(p, "Host: graph.facebook.com\r\n");
    p += sprintf(p, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" BOUNDARY "\r\n");
    p += sprintf(p, "Content-Length: %d\r\n", content_len);
    p += sprintf(p, "\r\n");
    SSL_write(ssl, writebuf, strlen(writebuf));

    SSL_write(ssl, data_file_header, strlen(data_file_header));
    SSL_write(ssl, myimage_png, myimage_png_len);

    SSL_write(ssl, data_end, strlen(data_end));

    n = SSL_read(ssl, readbuf, sizeof(readbuf));
    if (n > 0) {
        printf("read %d bytes\r\n", n);
        printf("++++++++ result ++++++++\r\n");
        printf("%s", readbuf);
        printf("-------- result --------\r\n");
    }
}

int create_socket(const char *hostname, const int port) {
    int sockfd;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;

    if ( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL ) {
        printf("cannot resolve hostname\r\n");
        abort();
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset( &dest_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) );
    dest_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    dest_addr.sin_port=htons(port);
    dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);

    if ( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &dest_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1 ) {
        printf("fail to connect\r\n");
    }

    return sockfd;
}

int main() {

    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL *ssl;
    int sock = 0;

    const char *hostname = "graph.facebook.com";
    const int port = 443;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    SSL_load_error_strings();

    if( SSL_library_init() < 0 )
        printf("fail to init ssl\r\n");

    if ( (ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method())) == NULL )
        printf("fail to create ssl context\r\n");

    //Disable SSLv2 and enable all workarounds for buggy servers
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_ALL | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2);
    SSL_CTX_set_mode(ctx, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
    SSL_CTX_set_mode(ctx, SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS);

    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

    if ( (sock = create_socket(hostname, 443)) < 0 )
        printf("fail to create socket\r\n");

    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock);

    if ( SSL_connect(ssl) != 1 )
        printf("fail to build ssl session\r\n");

    iotask(ssl);

    SSL_free(ssl);
    close(sock);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    printf("end ssl connection\r\n");
    return(0);
}
```